# css transition only for a:hover

Tags: hover, css-transitions

There is a bug in Safari 7.0.6!

The default link-color in most browsers is blue. So when I use this

```
a {
    color: #808080;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition: color 10s;
    -o-transition: color 10s;
    -ms-transition: color 10s;
    -moz-transition: color 10s;
    transition: color 10s;
}
a:hover {
    color: #B01617;
}
```

in a linked external CSS-file, not insite

```
<style type="text/css">...</style>
```

as does http://jsfiddle.net, the transition works not only for the hover effect. The transition from `blue` to `#808080` also needs `10s`.

Can anyone confirm this? Where can I report to Apple?

Comment: If you only want the transition to happen when you hover over the element, then move the transition code into the block with the hover selector. This will, however, make the transition back to the original color instantaneous.

Comment: I need the transition back to the original color also in 0.5s. Thank you but this doesn't help me. Only the transition from the browser-default-color (most blue) to the original color (#808080) has to be instantaneous.

Comment: It's unclear to me what your problem is, it'd help if you altered the wording of the question.

Comment: Ok, thank you DJDavid98! I tried a different browser and there is no issue. When you have Safari 7.0.6, can you confirm my problem?

Comment: I don't have safari, so no.